# Best mysql structure for my data table

Tags: mysql, database, schema

Im very new to mysql, and any help would be much appreciated!

I have my main table with product information. (9000+ products)

```
    id       name          size     color
    9809355  product one   small    blue
    0109425  product two   large    black
```

I also have cron script that that gets the following data of **each product** every hour (from ebay or amazon):

```
    id       price     timestamp
    9809355  $672.00   07/26/2012 @ 2:00pm
    0109425  $82.00    07/26/2012 @ 2:00pm
```

(prices are allways changing)

**What is the best way to store this data?**

my options seem to be creating a table for each product, or placing all my data into one table for product prices.

Comment: Steven, how long does this process take? I mean is it a few seconds every hour and all products are collected or is it rather product-by-product every few seconds?

Comment: And do you need to keep historical data in database or discard in upon update?

Comment: The script checks all the products one at a time, and stores the prices as it finds them, so it can take a while to complete

Comment: data is averaged and then discarded every day. the daily average is then averaged and discarded after a month.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Creating a table for each product is rarely ever the correct approach.  This would needlessly complicate joins -- if you wanted to obtain a list of all products, how would you do it with separate tables?

If you want to decouple the price data from the price details, you could create a price table that has a one-to-one relationship with the product information table.  I don't generally advocate for one-to-one relationships, but sometimes it is the right approach.

Comment: If I place all the products data into one table, it would be around .5 million entries. Wouldn't that slow down queries? Also I would only query the data for one product at a time, so it seems inefficient

Comment: If you have an index on the `id` column and you use a `WHERE id = ?` clause in your queries, the lookup should be very fast.  The index lookup will be O(log n) complexity; a search for a single row by its ID in a 500k-row table should take a *maximum* of 19 traversal operations on the index, assuming a balanced binary tree -- and the b-tree indexes used by mysql are usually more efficient than that.  (FYI, if `id` is the primary key then it has an implicit index defined on it already.)